# How to merge Angular code with C# and connect it to sql db

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

Here is the folder structure of my project in visual studio

```
UI
->App
    -->Directive
    -->Service
    -->Utilities
->Content
->Controllers
->Models
->Scripts
->Views
```

All the angular code is inside the app->directive folder. Scripts are inside the scripts folder and css inside the content folder.

I have worked on the front end part where the user selects inputs from dropdown. My query is how can i pass this dropdown value to backend using C#. and where do i have to create the C# file in the folder structure. How will i link the C# file with the angular code.

Once this is done, i have to interact with the SQL database too. I dont know where to put the sql code. The folder structure and interaction is confusing for me. Can someone please give me a simple example of how i can get started with. It will be great help.

I tried searching online and there are tons of different examples and its getting me more confused. Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the backend (c#), the service side, you can use web api to connect with your database and connect with the client-side (angularjs) through json data. There is also a tutorial by microsoft with an example with that architecture

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: thanks tunna. this is wat i was looking for. its a great help for me. thanks

Comment: This link  was helpful for our new Angular/c#/SQL project